# Is there any way to access a String variable inside of a for loop?

Tags: java

I need to access the two `String variables` `suit` and `rank`,
then use them outside of the `for loop`. Is this at all possible?

```
public class Deck {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int deck[] = new int[52];
        String suits[] = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
        String ranks[] = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) deck[i] = i;

        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            int index = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length);
            int temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[index];
            deck[index] = temp;
        }
        // randomizes the deck
        for(int i = 1; i < deck.length; i++) {
            String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];  // I want to access these two Strings
            String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];  // here
            System.out.println(rank + "\t" + suit);

        }
        // and use them here
        // I'm trying to make a poker game but need to use those two to deal a hand
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that? then `suit` or `rank` will hold only last value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to deal a *hand* then it seems to me you need a collection - after all, a player holds multiple cards.

I think you need to take a step back, rather than continuing with your current code. I'd do it something like this:

- Define one enum for suits
- Define one enum for ranks
- Create a `Card` class which has a suit and a rank
- Create a `Deck` class to store "cards remaining in the deck", starting with one of each card (or more)
- Create a `Player` class which has a collection of cards as the hand
- Create a `PokerGame` class (or something similar) as the entry point - that's the class which has `main` in. (It doesn't make much sense for it to be in `Deck`, in my opinion.)
- Deal from the deck to the player, as many cards as you want.

Comment: Ya that's true. Sorry if it was a dumb question. I've only been trying to teach myself this week. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user3136315: Not that dumb a question really - but it's worth learning the lesson that as soon as things start to be a bit odd, it's worth taking a step back and checking that what you're trying to achieve makes sense. I've often spent ages winning a small battle against code, only to find that I've lost the war by designing it badly to start with!

Comment: I've been trying to resolve this for about 2 hours now. Also I don't quite know what an enum is yet. Is that another variable type?

Answer (score 1):

Define the variables outside of the foor-loop, like here:

```
String suit;
String rank;
for(int i = 1; i < deck.length; i++) {
    suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];  // I want to access these two Strings
    rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];  // here
    System.out.println(rank + "\t" + suit);

    }
    // and use them here

    // I'm trying to make a poker game but need to use those two to deal a hand
}
```